# Rails 4: How can I import an Excel file directly from a URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, roo-gem

Navigate [here](https://www.spdrs.com/product/fund.seam?ticker=TOTL) and search for "Download All Holdings" and you will arrive at the [link](https://www.spdrs.com/site-content/xls/TOTL_All_Holdings.xls?fund=TOTL&docname=All+Holdings&onyx_code1=1286&onyx_code2=) to the file that I want to scrape (headers and cells contents).

Using open-uri or Roo returns the page source when I pass in the table link (not the table contents).

Using Ruby, how can I read the contents of this file? I would ideally like to extract the contents and save the original file in read-only format.

Note: I am already using Mechanize/Nokogiri to scrape and want to supplement/validate my scraping with linked Excel files like the one above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure to use `Roo::Spreadsheet` and not `Roo::Excelx`, because only  `Roo::Spreadsheet` can open remote URLs directly:

```
url = 'https://www.spdrs.com/site-content/xls/TOTL_All_Holdings.xls?fund=TOTL&docname=All+Holdings&onyx_code1=1286&onyx_code2='
sheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(url)
```

Comment: Works! (minus the extra ")" on line 2). Thanks.

Comment: Great! I've removed the extra paren

Comment: Thanks. I asked another very similar question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776734/rails-4-how-can-i-import-a-aspx-excel-file-directly-from-a-url) if you have a second to take a look. .aspx appears to be confusing Roo. Any work-arounds? Thanks a ton!